# BASH - If $TIME between 8am and 1pm do.., esle do.. Specifying time variables and if statements in BASH

Tags: mysql, bash, variables

I need to run a command when something is entered in BASH with a certain time-frame, and if it's not that time run another command. Here's what I've got so far, but it doesn't appear to be working..

```
FLATTIME=$(date "+%H%M")
FLATTIME=${FLATTIME##0}

if ! [[ $FLATTIME -gt 1130 ]] ; then
mysql --host=192.168.0.100 --user=myself --password=mypass thedb << EOF
INSERT INTO $STAFFID values ('','$STAFFID','$THETIME','','$THEDATE','$DAYOFWEEK');
EOF

else
mysql --host=192.168.1.92 --user=myself --password=mypass thedb << EOF
UPDATE $STAFFID SET Out_Time='$THETIME' WHERE date='$THEDATE';
EOF
fi
```

Ideally what I'd like is to have something like: if the time is between 8am and 1pm do the first command, if the time is between 1pm and 11pm do the second command, else echo "someone's been at work too long". I've tried a few variations but no luck, it just seems to run the first command whatever I do..

Comment: This may be too obvious, but have you run this script at a time later than 1130? Or commented out the `date` command and hard-coded a timestamp for testing? I tried your `if-else` structure on my machine and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In this case, you just need to look at the hour. Also, bash has syntax to specify the radix of a number, so you don't have to worry about 08 and 09 being invalid octal numbers:

```
H=$(date +%H)
if (( 8 <= 10#$H && 10#$H < 13 )); then 
    echo between 8AM and 1PM
elif (( 13 <= 10#$H && 10#$H < 23 )); then 
    echo between 1PM and 11PM
else
    echo go to bed
fi
```

"10#$H" is the contents of the variable, in base 10.

---

Actually, better to use `%k` instead of `%H` to avoid the invalid octal problem.

```
H=$(date -d '08:45' "+%H")
(( 13 <= H && H < 23 )) && echo ok || echo no
```

```
bash: ((: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

versus

```
H=$(date -d '08:45' "+%k")
# ....................^^
(( 13 <= H && H < 23 )) && echo ok || echo no
```

```
no
```